# JAVA: Invoke an AIDL Service method that expects another Interface as a parameter

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-service, aidl

I am trying to invoke a **Service method** that expects another **Interface as a parameter**. I must point out that I need to make this using **Reflection** without actually knowing the source code. So, using Reflection I got the Interface corresponding to the Service whose methods I need to call. Then I managed to create an object for that Interface. After that I am able to call the functions and for most of them this works, but I have a problem when a parameter is another Interface. For example let`s say we have the following method in **IPermissionService**:

```
public void addPermissionRevokedListener(IPermissionRevokedListener listener)
```

While generating the parameter for this method my code finds 2 possible classes:

```
IPermissionRevokedListener$Default
IPermissionRevokedListener$Stub$Proxy
```

Currently it takes the first one and calls the constructor to create the object.
Everything seems fine till this point, but then when the call is performed an Exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    method addPermissionRevokedListener argument 1 has type IPermissionRevokedListener, 
        got IPermissionRevokedListener$Default
```

I have been digging around and trying some combinations but I could not find a solution for this. Is there a way to solve this?

*For those not familiar with AIDL, this is how usually the Interface part looks like:*

```
public interface IPermissionRevokedListener extends android.os.IInterface
{
    public static class Default implements IPermissionRevokedListener
    {...}
    public static abstract class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements IPermissionRevokedListener
    {
        private static class Proxy implements IPermissionRevokedListener
        {...}
    }
}
```

Also, one possibility would be to try to connect to the other service and acquire the Interface object, similar to the way the first one was done, but I am not sure how to figure out which Service it is just based on the Interface information. Also, I might end up with pretty much the same problem with the only difference being **IPermissionRevokedListener$Stub$Proxy** instead of **IPermissionRevokedListener$Default** since **IPermissionRevokedListener$Stub$Proxy** is given when acquiring Interface from a bound Service). But, I would like to know if there is a possibility to find the Service based on the Interface as well.

Anyway, currently I would be happy if the **$Default** object can somehow be used.

**EDIT:** What is bugging me the most is that **$Default** implements the needed interface, but is somehow not accepted.
Also, I just tried to use **Reflection Proxy** to create Interface implementation on fly and got a similar **Exception**:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
        method addPermissionRevokedListener argument 1 has type IPermissionRevokedListener, 
            got $Proxy4
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time I think I finally know what the problem is. While searching for Interface implementations I used **Dex Class Loader** to load and check Classes. All that works fine but looks like that is causes problems later on. When I changed from the **Dex Class Loader** to the Class Loader retrieved from the Interface in question there was no problem in invoking the method with **$Default**. Although now I need to refactor my code with this new information in mind.

I will leave this here because who knows maybe someone goes the same way and ends up questioning the World around him :)

Also, the other question still remains: Is it possible to find the Service based just on Interface details?